# Create a shopping cart in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to implement shopping cart in Django Rest Framework.
I store information about the shopping cart inside the models.
I don't want to use a session for this and I want to save it in the database.
users must be logged in to create and add products to the cart.
But I want users to be able to add the product to the cart without logging into the site.(Implementation of shopping cart for guest users)
I would be very grateful if you could guide me. Thanks

```
My Model :

class Cart(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()

 My View:        

  

class AddToCartApi(APIView):
    serializer_class = AddToCartSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        user_id = request.user.id
        data = serializer.validated_data
        
        Cart.objects.create(
            user_id=user_id,
            product_id=data['product_id'],
            quantity=data['quantity'],                
        )
        return Response(....)
```

Comment: "[...] users must be logged in to create and add products to the cart" and "But I want them to be able to add the product to the cart without logging in" does not really make sense together or I don't understand your question

Comment: I want users to be able to add the product to the cart without logging into the site

Comment: Implementation of shopping cart for guest users

Answer (score 1):

Well, in scenarios where you want users to add/update the shopping cart without logging :

Solution 1:
You have to implement the same in client side i.e. If your client is interacting through web browser you can make use of local/session storage. Later when the user logs in, you can save all information in database.